# Pandas Cast Int64 (capitalised) to int64

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I'm getting a resultant DataFrame which has column type as `Int64`.

How can I convert it to `int64`?

Below code did not work.

```
print(region_ids.mycolumn.dtypes) 
region_ids['mycolumn'].astype(int64)    
print(region_ids.mycolumn.dtypes)
```

Actual Result:

```
Int64
Int64
```

Expected Result:

```
Int64
int64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign it as well, and also use it in a string like the below:

```
region_ids['mycolumn'] = region_ids['mycolumn'].astype('int64')
```

There actually the different types...

As @tdelaney mentioned:

> They aren't the same type. an Int64 is a nullable array and is implemented with a shadow column that tells you whether a given cell should be pandas.NA. The problem with int64 is that if you have NaN values, the column type can change to float. If you don't have NaN, then int64 is the better choice. [pandas.arrays.IntegerArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html#pandas-arrays-integerarray)

Comment: Thanks! It worked after I assigned the column back to orginal DF. Btw, I think it should be ```region_ids.loc[:,'mycolumn'] = region_ids['mycolumn'].astype('int64')  ``` instead.

Comment: Tbey aren't the same type. an `Int64` is a nullable array and is implemented with a shadow column that tells you whether a given cell should be `pandas.NA`. The problem with `int64` is that if you have NaN values, the column type can change to float. If you don't have NaN, then `int64` is the better choice. [pandas.arrays.IntegerArray](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntegerArray.html#pandas-arrays-integerarray)

Comment: @tdelaney Edited in your comment

Comment: The string alias "Int64" (note the capital "I", to differentiate from NumPy’s 'int64' dtype,  So, by default if any of the dataFrame column has `NaN` representation then it will be converted to `Int64` as numpy style, here is the pandas doc which explains it well [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)